# Chromecast Application published but not show on store

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I published my app on Google Cast SDK but it still does not show on

https://www.google.com/chromecast/built-in/apps/

And my app does not open android tv app like when using dev mode.
What should I do right now?
Note: Published 1 week ago.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure this out?